# Prevent JFace TableColumn from being resized to 0 width

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, jface

I am using a JFace TableViewer and TableColumnLayout. How can i set a columns minimum width, or at least prevent it from being resized to 0 width?

```
TableColumnLayout layout = new TableColumnLayout();
parent.setLayout(layout);
TableViewer viewer = new TableViewer(parent, SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.BORDER);

//adding a few columns like this
TableColumn col = new TableColumn(viewer.getTable(), SWT.LEFT);
int minWidth = 100; 
layout.setColumnData(col, new ColumnWeightData(10, minWidth, true));
col.setMoveable(true);
...
```

It appears that the minWidth parameter of ColumnWeightData is not honored, i can still resize the columns to 0 width.

Using something like this works:

```
col.addControlListener(new ControlListener(){
    @Override
    public void controlMoved(ControlEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void controlResized(ControlEvent e) {
        if(col.getWidth()<5)
            col.setWidth(5);

    }});
```

But that seems rather ugly, is there a cleaner way to do it?

Comment: Helmuth M., when I do exactly like this, and 1) when I very slowly move (left) line/grid of say column 3 exactly on (right grid/line of) column 2, then column 2 is not visible anymore. Thus the width of column 2 is not maintained to 5. Although I can again move line of column 3 and make column 2 visible. but why the width is not maintained to 5 of column 2 ? any idea what I might be doing wrong ? 2) When I repeat this behavior three times i.e. I move column 2,3 and 4 to first column-1 one by one, and make it invisible. I can not retrieve it again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Table` has no built-in support for this. So a `Resize` listener - like you have shown in your question - is the only way.